# DoubleClick floating ad doesn't stay fixed on the page

Tags: html, banner, floating, double-click-advertising

I am creating a floating banner ad that is supposed to stay fixed to the bottom of the page. I created the ad and uploaded it to DoubleClick Studio. In the preview tab I'm seeing that the ad doesn't stay fixed to the bottom of the page and instead moves up and down with the content as it scrolls. I've inspected the banner on Chrome to find that the container div that houses the ad is set to position absolute instead of position fixed. If it was set to fixed this would solve the issue, but I have no control over changing the positioning of the container of the ad, I can only say where the ad should be positioned - bottom, top, left or right.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Does anyone have any ideas for how this can be fixed? I've reached out to a few people at DoubleClick hoping that they'll have some suggestions, but I thought that the stackoverflow community would be able to help as well.

If it helps, I used Google Web Designer to create the banner ad. This is the first HTML5 ad that I've created and uploaded to DoubleClick Studio. All previous ads were Flash banners.

Answer (score 1):

As I remember correctly, floating ad will appear on top of the website contents and then fade away.

As a designer & banner developer you should consider to develop the ad and the publisher will put it on their website. So if the publishter on the specsheet wrote they will align the ad on the bottom of the page, they will.

To check on how it will look on the bottom of the page, you can go to DoubleClick Studio -> creatives tab -> preview section => Then choose 'Show Details' button. There will be expanded tab on left hand side.

Then select the 'Display Properties'.

This is the area you can place your ad on the screen for test purposes.
But keep in mind this is only for test and the publisher will place your ad based on their specifications.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Majid for the answer. This ad is a floating ad that sits at the bottom of the page, also known as a "catfish" ad. I did have a look in the section of DoubleClick Studio that you suggested and I see the same kind of behaviour there that is happening on the site.